# Setting "SameSite" cookie value to "none” not working when anotating "DefaultCookieSerializer" as "@Component"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, samesite

Recently I had to change `SameSite` value from `Lax` to `None`. For that I decided to use `CookieSerializer` and strange stuff begins here. Whenever I define cookie serializer like this:

```
@Bean
fun cookieSerializer() = DefaultCookieSerializer().apply {
    setSameSite(SameSiteCookies.NONE.value)
}
```

It works, but if I move this code to separate file and annotate it as `@Component` it dosn't work anymore.

Maybe anyone knows what might be the reason? What is the difference between these and what might be possible reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: Maybe the application doesn't scan this new file? Could you tell me more about the error?

Comment: There is no error just when I log in to application from front end cookies SameSite value is Lax instead of None and it is definitely scanned it is with other components